# Naming Elixir GenServer Processes differently from the module that implements them

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a module named `Tornado` that implements a GenServer and I'm trying to spawn it as a process with a different name than the name of the module itself. 
According to the [Elixir Docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html) a GenServer Process can be registered by giving an atom as a parameter

```
children = [
  worker(Tornado, [[], [name: :tornado_server]])
]
```

But when I try to call a function on it I get an error:

```
iex(2)> :tornado_server.send_requests 
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function :tornado_server.send_requests/1 (module :tornado_server is not available)
```

I also tried to change `:tornado_server` to `TornadoServer`

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function     TornadoServer.send_requests/1 (module TornadoServer is not available)
```

**EDIT**

Here is the Tornado Module

```
defmodule Tornado do
  use GenServer

  # Public API
  def start_link(state,  opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link __MODULE__, state, opts
  end

  def send_requests(requests) do
    GenServer.cast(self, {:send_requests, requests})
  end

  def get_responses do
    GenServer.call(self, :get_responses )
  end

  # GenServer API
  def init(state) do
    # creaza 10 Ci
    { :ok, state }
  end

  def handle_cast({:send_requests, requests}, state) do
    state = state ++ [{requests, "127.0.0.1\n"}]
    {:noreply, state }
  end

  def handle_call(:get_responses, _from, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end
end
```

And here is the Supervisor that starts it:

```
defmodule TornadoSupervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__,[])
  end

  def init([]) do
    children = [
      worker(Tornado, [[], [name: :tornado_server]])
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

Basically I would like to call it like this:

```
 > TornadoSupervisor.start_link
 > TornadoServer.send_requests some_requests_array
 > TornadoServer.get_responses
```

**Later Edit**
Apparently it works if I do it like this

```
 > GenServer.cast(TornadoServer, {:send_requests,requests})
 > GenServer.call(TornadoServer, :get_responses )
```

But I find this syntax too verbose.

Answer (score 3):

Calling your function with `:tornado_server.send_requests` will look for the erlang module `tornado_server` which is unlikely what you want.

You still need to call the function on your module, the name is used in place of the pid, not the module name.

Without seeing your module, it is difficult to advise further. I would suggest reading http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html then http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html to see how named processes work.

**EDIT**

`GenServer.cast/call` expect a pid (or registered name) as the first argument. The pid you are using (the result of `self`) is the caller, not the running GenServer.

You should either store the pid and do something like:

```
{:ok, pid} = Tornado.start_link()
Tornado.send_requests(pid, some_requests_array)
Tornado.get_responses(pid)
```

Or you should replace your implementation to use the provided name:

```
  def send_requests(requests) do
    GenServer.cast(:tornado_server, {:send_requests, requests})
  end

  def get_responses do
    GenServer.call(:tornado_server, :get_responses )
  end
```

It is not really clear why you don't want to use the module name though. It is a pretty common convention for a GenSever that you only want 1 of.

Comment: I've added the implementation. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: "It is a pretty common convention for a GenSever that you only want 1 of." I see. There's actually another reason I want to have different names for my processes. I have another module `Queue` that implements a queue of requests. I want to spawn multiple queues, one queue each domain name( `Queue.domain1.com`, `Queue.domain2.com` and so on). There I basically have only one module but I want the process names to be given dynamically for each domain.

Comment: I the first solution you wrote shouldn't it be `Tornado`( aka the name of the module) instead of `TornadoServer`( the name of the process)?

Comment: The second solution works when calling `Tornado.send_requests`. Thank you!